# Add margin to DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How do I add margin or padding to a DataGridTextColumn?

Answer (score 43):

Answers without sample code aren't very helpful.  Use this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The `x` prefix comes from `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`.  I used a business object that has a public `Name` property.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`ElementStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle.aspx)/[`EditingElementStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle.aspx).